# What is the blessing said over little plants' fruit?

Tags: blessing, fruits

There is a blessing over fruits of trees another blessing over fruits of the earth. Which blessing we should say over fruits of plants like strawberry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strawberries are not a "tree" -- it's not the same plant producing new fruit. So we say "for the fruit of the ground."

Plants that scientists say produce fruit each year but grow very low to the ground -- such as cranberries -- are "fruit of the ground" according to common Ashkenazic practice, although the Talmud sounds like they should be "fruit of the tree."

Comment: Hi Shalom (that's redundant :-) Maybe you can edit in your answer what is considered the max height for *adamah* & after that it is considered a tree? I would find that useful, as well as I think, the O.P.